# Find the area common to the inside of the cardioid $r = 1+\sin \theta$ and the outside of the cardioid $r = 1 + \cos \theta$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, area

[Function Plotter graph](https://functionplotter.com/#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):

---

[image]

---

I think the formula is

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (\text{outer})^2 - (\text{inner})^2 d\theta$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are [where they intersect](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(theta)%3Dcos(theta),%200%20%3C%3D%20theta%20%3C%3D%202pi) in $[0, 2\pi]$.

This is what I got based on that

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{3\pi/4}^{5\pi/4} (1+\sin \theta)^2 - (1+\cos \theta)^2 d\theta$$

Is that right?

Comment: Which cardioid is "inner" varies by angle.  You need to be careful, and divide the area you want into pieces.

Comment: @vadim123 $[3\pi/4$,$\pi]$ and then $[\pi$,$5\pi/4]$?